# transfer a table in the other?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

I have 2 tables. 
The first table called players, with the columns (id, playerid, name) 
The second table is called locker, with the columns (id, playerid, schliessfachinv) 
I want to insert the second table in the first, where the playerid are equal. 
can someone help me, because there are about 2,000 lines.

Comment: Need more details. Sounds more like you want to `UPDATE` an existing row in the players table. Are you trying to get schliessfachinv into the players table?

Comment: my english is not the best, 
I want the schliessfachinv add to table 1 where playerid are equal to table 2!, 
but many thanks for the extremely quick help

Comment: Have you already altered the players table to have the column schliessfachinv?

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new rows, `UPDATE` is for changing rows. If you're adding a new row, how can the IDs be equal?

Comment: so i will post 2 pictures now, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmo56sk26izyw30/schliessfach.PNG?dl=0    https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf5dgqijpn18zhg/playertable.PNG?dl=0   the inv from schliessfach need to be in the playertable

Comment: playerid have to be equel, not the ids

Comment: i think it is like , insert into players schliessfach where schliessfach.playerid = players.playerid, but i need the date from the second table, sorry for my english, hope you can help me

Comment: The columns in your images don't match what you said in the question. You need to explain what you want better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little confused from your description but this sounds like what you want. I'd test this before doing it in production to make sure it does what you wanted.

```
UPDATE players p
JOIN schliessfach s
    ON p.playerid = s.playerid
SET p.lockers= s.lockers
```

Comment: i get an error, iam so sorry for my nooblike, iam only an arma 3 programming pro:), so i will post 2 pictures again, because my english is to bad for a right question. players table = https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf5dgqijpn18zhg/playertable.PNG?dl=0 and this is the schliessfach table https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmo56sk26izyw30/schliessfach.PNG?dl=0 so i think an update is the right way. and many thanks for your help. i called the rows lockers now, because i think it is eassier for you to understand my qustion

Comment: i get an error again, here the picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoq5r0sx2s7m5r4/problem.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @etrex2k4 I modified answer again. My original answer was for MSSQL.

Comment: You are the best of all, should you ever Arma 3 games, you're welcome to our server, the community thanks you http://ruhrpott-life.de/index.php/Thread/160-Schliessfach-problem-bald-ein-Ende/?postID=465#post465

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO players (playerid, name)
SELECT l.playerid, l.schliessfachinv
FROM locker AS l
JOIN players AS p ON l.playerid = p.playerid
```

This will insert rows from `locker` into `players`, setting the `name` equal to `schliessfachinv`.

Comment: i get an error, iam so sorry for my nooblike, iam only an arma 3 programming pro:), so i will post 2 pictures again, because my english is to bad for a right question. players table = dropbox.com/s/pf5dgqijpn18zhg/playertable.PNG?dl=0 and this is the schliessfach table dropbox.com/s/vmo56sk26izyw30/schliessfach.PNG?dl=0 so i think an update is the right way. and many thanks for your help